# Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x}$$

Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ at which the series converges. Converges absolutely. Find all intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ where the series defining $f$ converges uniformly, and all intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ on which $f$ is continuous

I'm very confused about how to think about this

Comment: you just need to know the definitions of conditional convergence, absolute convergence, uniform convergence and apply them to your series, it is not so complicate

Comment: Do you know the conditions which guarantee the convergence of an alternating series?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales it's not quite so simple if I'm not mistaken, at least for $x<0$.

Comment: @qbert My question was intended to gauge just how confused the OP is. The first two should be easy aside from the negative integers.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales fair enough and definitely true about the first two and uniform convergence on the nonegatives